# How do i display object on Javascript

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch-api

I am currently doing a course on Udemy on JavaScript and i have been stuck on a project for a couple of weeks, I have followed the instruction to the best of my abilities many times but i seem to be missing a vital part that is stopping the project form displaying an object.

The purpose of this project to display cocktail drinks and the ingredients when you submit your favourite cocktail into a form. I have  four JavaScript files app.js this is the main section of the JS code, then CocktailAPI.js this holds a class that handles the API queries, then we have UI.js this is for the interface behaviour and lastly the part i have not yet reached is the COcktailDB.js.

The problem i am facing is that i have created the class that handles the API request and the tutor starts by converting it into json and then turn the response into a object which is then logged on the console log to prove that everything is working fine.The problem i am facing is that even though i have copied the tutor the object does not display on my console and i get a error message that reads:

> Access to fetch at 'http://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=vodka' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I have checked the url many times and even copied and paste the url to eliminate that as the problem, i have solved this problem before but ended up starting the project again because i encountered another problem and though starting again would solve it. However when i reached this point again i didn't not know what i done to solve the problem as i tried so many things.

As there is 2 files that are currently in use at the moment as i am still quite early into the project there is nothing on 2 files so i will only post the 2 js files.If this is not enough please let me know what i need to add.

***app.js***

```
//Instanciate the classes
const ui = new UI(),
  cocktail = new CocktailAPI();


//Create the event listeners
function eventListeners() {
  //Add event listeners when the form is submittted
  const searchForm = document.querySelector('#search-form');
  if (searchForm) {
    searchForm.addEventListener('submit', getCocktails);
  }
}

eventListeners();


//Get cocktail function
function getCocktails(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  const searchTerm = document.querySelector('#search').value;

  //Check something is on the search input
  if (searchTerm === '') {
    ui.printMessage('Please add something intot the form', 'danger');
  } else {
    //Query by name of the drink
    cocktail.getDrinkByName(searchTerm)
      .then(cocktails => {
        console.log(cocktails);
      })
  }
}
```

***Cocktail.js***

```
class UI {
  //Display a custom message
  printMessage(message, className) {
    const div = document.createElement('div');

    //Add the HTML
    div.innerHTML = `
          <div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-${className}">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">X</button>
          ${message}
          </div>
      `;

    //Insert befrore
    const reference = document.querySelector('.jumbotron h1');
    const parentNode = reference.parentElement;
    parentNode.insertBefore(div, reference);

    //Remove after 3 seconds
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.querySelector('.alert').remove();
    }, 3000);

  }
}
```

***cocktailAPI.js***

```
class CocktailAPI {
  //Get recipe by name
  async getDrinkByName(name) {

    //Search by name
    const apiResponse = await fetch(`http://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=${name}`);

    //returns json respnse
    cocktails = await apiResponse.json();

    return {
      cocktails
    }
  }
}
```

It may become clearer what i am trying to produce when you load up all the files

I understand that this may not be enough information but if you ask me i will be able to explain in more detail, but the code is mean to display the response of the API in the console log with all the properties

I will copy the code so that it can be viewed if any one want the files itself to look into more deeply.

Comment: Can you post the code for the `CocktailAPI` class?

Comment: class CocktailAPI{
    //Get recipe by name
    async getDrinkByName(name){
        
        //Search by name
        const apiResponse = await fetch(`http://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=${name}`);

        //returns json respnse
        cocktails = await apiResponse.json();

        return{
            cocktails
        }
    }

}

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are using `http` to communicate with the API. If you change `http://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=${name}` to `https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=${name}` (***notice the `https`***) it should work for you.

```js
class CocktailAPI {
  //Get recipe by name
  async getDrinkByName(name) {
    try {
      //Search by name
      const apiResponse = await fetch(`https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=${name}`);
      //returns json respnse
      let cocktails = await apiResponse.json();
      return { cocktails };
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  }
}

let cocktails_api = new CocktailAPI();

cocktails_api
  .getDrinkByName("vodka")
  .then(vodka => { console.log(vodka) })
  .catch(err => { console.log("ERR", err) });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your request for the JSON data must be served over `https://` and not `http://` since `thecocktaildb.com` most probably added an [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) wildcard that only accept `https` requests and not `http` requests in their [response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Response_header).

Just replace the `http` in your fetch request with an `https` like this:

```
fetch(`https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=${name}`);
```

Check and run the following code snippet for a practical example of the above:

```js
async function hello(name) {
  const apiResponse = await fetch(`https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=${name}`);
  let cocktails = await apiResponse.json();
  console.log(cocktails);
  return cocktails;
}

hello("vodka");
```

Comment: Cool api otherwise